# .htaccess url secure

Tags: php, .htaccess, server-side

Hello everybody :D I would like to ask for your help on this problem. 
I have a .htacess and I want to make my files secure. I want to make a url for my css to different from its original path. Its like hiding the directory of the css or removing it from the url but still when the browser fetches the file it points to the write file path.

**Example**

***Orignal path***

Directory: /public_html/styles/main.css

Web URL: www.domain.com/styles/main.css

***What I want:***

Directory: /public_html/styles/main.css

Web URL: www.domain.com/main.css

Comment: Do you want this to happen for every CSS file or only main.css? Or for any file in the styles directory?

Comment: as possible any file.. but want to assign a base url in each file... can this be done?

Comment: Any reason you want to hide css folder? What "security" you are talking about?

Comment: hmmm.. not realy just css but also other directories..I had some experience that the directory was attacked by hackers and only the directory... deleted all files on the directory and the site gone crazy...

Comment: this attack can be done only from *inside* of the site. no file can be deleted by just accessing a directory from outside! you have to improve your site security, not h

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel ahhh ok.. so the problem is on the server... hmmm... many thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to ask for your help on this problem.

I don't see any problem here.

> I want to make my files secure.

It just makes no sense. CSS files intended to be "insecure", i.e. accessed by everyone.

> I want to make a url for my css to different from its original path.

It makes no sense again. **Hiding directory path doesn't make the file secure.**

Comment: I want to files inside the directory where the css file to be secure.. sorry for a having this crazy question...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have mod_rewrite and put this somewhere close to the top of your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.css$ /styles/$1.css [L]
```

Comment: I think this is a good answer. It shouldn't have been down voted.